# How to avoid to write `@ApiProperty()` in each dto for NestJs-swagger

Tags: javascript, typescript, swagger, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I'm researching the way on how to avoid to specify @ApiProperty() in each dto.

I know there is exist a way to create file `nest-cli.json`, and if you specify `Promise<DTO>` in your controller in nest-swagger it will produce the output dto from the route.

The structure looks like this:

`nest-cli.json`

```
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "@nestjs/swagger",
        "options": {
          "introspectComments": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`controller.ts`

```
@Get()
  async getMonitors (): Promise<OutputMonitorsDto> { // <-- Here is my outputDto
    return this.monitorsService.getMonitors()
  }
```

And in swagger it shows something like this:
[image]

However, is there any way to setup NestJs to have the same things with inputDTO and not to write in each dto `@ApiProperty`?

As in example below:

`ExampleDto.ts`

```
export class GetListUsersDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsString()
  name: string
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsString()
  email: string
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsString()
  publicApiKey: string
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsBoolean()
  isAdmin: boolean
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsBoolean()
  isDesigner: boolean
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsBoolean()
  isEditor: boolean
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsBoolean()
  isEnabled: boolean
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsString()
  boughtProduct: string
}
```

And only after @ApiProperty it will show the structure as shown above for input in swagger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way around decorating your DTO properties. However, if your DTOs have a lot in common, you might be looking for *mapped types*. Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/mapped-types).

These essentially allow you to transform existing types to keep your DTOs DRY.

Comment: I'd like to note that, as per @Deivy Gutierrez's answer, for those using the Nest CLI, there is a plugin that will decorate your DTOs for you. For those not using Nest CLI, you'll have to decorate your properties or come up with a custom solution.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using cli-plugin you don't need to add @ApiProperty. Check docs [openapi/cli-plugin](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/cli-plugin)

try this

```
export class CreateUserDto {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  roles: RoleEnum[] = [];
  @IsOptional()
  isEnabled?: boolean = true;
}
```

Comment: Using this plugin is the correct answer. https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/cli-plugin#using-the-cli-plugin

Answer (score 5):

Using the plugin resolved this issue for me, see https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/cli-plugin#using-the-cli-plugin.

To enable the plugin, open `nest-cli.json` (if you use Nest CLI) and add the following plugins configuration:

```
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": ["@nestjs/swagger"]
  }
}
```

Then this will automatically apply the @ApiProperty() without having to add it

```
export class CreateUserDto {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  roles: RoleEnum[] = [];
  @IsOptional()
  isEnabled?: boolean = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that using

> Using the plugin resolved this issue for me, see https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/cli-plugin#using-the-cli-plugin.

your DTO file should be named **<my_dto_name>.dto.ts**

Comment: Can you please add explanation why?

Comment: Because the documentation of the CLI Plugin in the Options section says that it's the default convention @daniilsinelnik

Answer (score -1):

Simply adding this in your dto file will auto apply for all properties

```
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
```

Magic will happen to wherever you need it.
Hope this helps.

Comment: above works for me